# Animation doesn't work?

Tags: swift, jquery-animate, uistoryboard

I'm trying to rotate an imageview and which was working but when i load that screen from another screen animation doesn't work.

```
class LoadingRequestViewController: UIViewController ,UICollectionViewDelegate,GMSMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
//UI OutletControls
@IBOutlet weak var loadingImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var mapView: GMSMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
//UI OutletControls


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadingImg.startRotating()

}



func TimerStoppedTrue() {
    TimerStopped = true
    NSLog("TimerStopped\(TimerStopped)")
}

@IBAction func CancelHireAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.timer.invalidate()
    self.CancelHire(self.HireID)
}
```

}

```
extension UIView {
func startRotating(duration: Double = 1) {
    let kAnimationKey = "rotation"

    if self.layer.animationForKey(kAnimationKey) == nil {
        let animate = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        animate.duration = duration
        animate.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        animate.fromValue = 0.0
        animate.toValue = Float(M_PI * 2.0)
        self.layer.addAnimation(animate, forKey: kAnimationKey)
    }


}
func stopRotating() {
    let kAnimationKey = "rotation"

    if self.layer.animationForKey(kAnimationKey) != nil {
        self.layer.removeAnimationForKey(kAnimationKey)
    }
}
```

}

when i calling LoadingRequestViewController like following animation doesn't work.But individually it's working.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoadingSTBID") as! LoadingRequestViewController

    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add it in viewwillAppear. It should work fine!